# How to insert image with transparent with xsl-fo?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using **xsl-fo** to generate PDF and I would like to insert an image with transparent (exp: 25%, 50%,...). The transparent value depended on input by the client and save in the database. I'm using `fo:external-graphic` tag to achieve that, but this tag hasn't properties transparent or equivalent. How do I resolve this issue?
Here my code:

```
<#assign cellPadding = "1pt">
<#assign dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy">
<#macro encodeText textValue>${Static["org.moqui.util.StringUtilities"].encodeForXmlAttribute(textValue!"", false)}</#macro>

<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="ArialUni, ArialUniBold, ArialUniItalic" font-size="10pt">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="letter-portrait" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in"
                               margin-top="0.05in" margin-bottom="0.1in" margin-left="0in" margin-right="0in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="0.05in" margin-bottom="0in" margin-left="0.5in"/>
            <fo:region-before margin-left="0in" margin-right="0in"/>
            <fo:region-after extent="0.2in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="letter-portrait" id="mainSequence">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="0in" left="0" width="8.5in" height="11in">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <image xlink:href="${imageLocation.getUri()}" opacity="1" width="8.5in" height="11in" scaling="non-uniform"/>
                        </svg>
                    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" font-size="8pt">
            <fo:block border-top="thin solid black">
                <fo:block text-align="center">Trang <fo:page-number/></fo:block>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>test image</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

and the result is:
[image]

My origin image:
[image]

Comment: One way you could try is not to insert the raster image directly but rather the embed it as an SVG snippet with e.g. `<fo:instream-foreign-object><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><image href="image.png" opacity="0.5"/></svg></<fo:instream-foreign-object>`. But I don't know how well that works with FO renderers.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks you martin, but the images are not displayed full, I try using the properties **width="8.5in" height="11in" scaling="non-uniform"**, but it does not affect and still display part of image, can you give me the docs of <SVG> and <image> tag and theirs property

Comment: Please show the XSL FO code you use and state the formatter you are using. Because of you are simply using an instream-foreign-object and expect it to be the size of a whole page, that may not work.

Comment: @KevinBrown Hi Kevin, I've added my code, the pdf result, and my image,  my expectation is the image is the background border for my pdf document, but it seem to show part of image and the position is wrong too

Comment: What happens if you set `svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%"` for the SVG `svg` element inside of the `instreeam-foreign-object`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen great martin, it's work, I edit my code like this `<fo:instream-foreign-object>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="8.5in" height="11in">
                            <image xlink:href="${logoLocation.getUri()}" opacity="0.8" width="8.51in" height="11in" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
                        </svg>
                    </fo:instream-foreign-object>`. Thank you so much